# HttpContext.Current.Session["list"] == null in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Any ideas/suggestions to why I get  (HttpContext.Current.Session["list"] == null)  in Firefox but not in IE? The check is called in .cs

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: Is HttpContext.Current null as well?

Comment: it is not. i did a check .. found out that under current notification i get : 'HttpContext.Current.CurrentNotification' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' ... mmm

Answer (score 3):

That may happen if you are using a cookie for the session identifier and you have cookies disabled in your browser.

Comment: my cookie is enabled in firefox

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling cookies